# What will be the minimum value of the function $f(x)=\arcsin(x)\uparrow\uparrow(2k)$ as $k \to \infty$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, power-towers

Consider the following two functions involving power towers; $$f(x)=\arcsin(x)\uparrow\uparrow(2k)$$ $$g(x)=\arcsin(x)\uparrow\uparrow(2k-1)$$
Where $k\in \mathbb{Z}^+$. The global minimum of $f(x)$ can be described as being point $P(a,b)$. What would happen to the values of $a$ and $b$ as $k \to \infty$? Will they both approach $0$ or will they converge to a non-zero number?

(Note: I've included function $g(x)$ to act as a comparison to $f(x)$; I don't believe it's actual required to find the solution for this question)

[image]

Comment: The $\color{DarkBlue}{\arcsin x}$ is just a distraction. See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration#Infinite_heights).

Answer (score 0):

The $\arcsin$ doesn't really do anything. Consider instead:

$$f_n(x)=x\uparrow\uparrow n$$

We have for even $n$,

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}f_{2n}(x)=\begin{cases}f_e(x),&0<x<e^{-e}\\f(x),&e^{-e}\le x\le e^{1/e}\end{cases}$$

and for odd $n$,

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}f_{2n+1}(x)=\begin{cases}f_o(x),&0<x<e^{-e}\\f(x),&e^{-e}\le x\le e^{1/e}\end{cases}$$

where $f^{-1}(x)=\sqrt[x]x$ and $f_e$ and $f_o$ are two different branches to the solution of $y=x^{x^y}$ which are not solutions to $y=x^y$.

[Graph of the limit](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/mco2n8kobr).

So the limit of the infinums are $0$ for odds and $f(e^{-e})=e^{-1}$ for the evens.